# what are the differences between "past week" and "last week"?

Tags: grammar, phrases, differences

What are the the differences in meaning between the following phrases:

> *past week*

And

> *last week*

Please try to explain it with as many examples as possible!

Comment: You always put the definite article in front of *past week*

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 5):

The difference is  "past week" would be to count back exactly a week from now, while "last week" is the calendar week preceding the present week. "Past week" is usually used when going through something/event. "Last week" is usually used to point to that particular week.

> Example:
>
> For the past week, it was raining heavily.
>
> Last week, it was raining heavily.

Answer (score 3):

The "past week" refers to the *most recent* week. If this is the fourth week of July, the "past" week would be the third week of July.

The "last week" refers to the *final* week in a series. If the fourth week of July is the last, or final of four weeks of July, the current week would be the *last* week of July.

"Last" week can be used for the "past" week, if the implication is that the "past" week" is the last of all weeks *up to now*.

The converse is not necessarily true; the "past week" cannot generally be used to describe the "last week." Unless we were in say, the first week of August, in which case the "past week" would describe the "last week" of July.